# Regular expression to match again plain text

Tags: regex

I would like to extract text from this string

```
Name:
    Franco Donezzi  
Phone:
    01234567890
Email: 
    franco@franco.com

Arrival date:
    16/12/2014
Departure date:
    28/12/2014
Guests:
    2 adults, 0 children

Further info:
    this is the text I want to match. there could be any amount of plain text here spread over multiple lines. sldkfjsldkfjs
```

I would like to extract 'Franco Donezzi', '0123457890','franco@franco.com' etc etc

I have always been able to extract either using reg-ex against html or by using simple-html-dom. There is a hacky way to do it by matching up to the next colon and then removing the corresponding word from the matched string (e.g. Phone) but is there a better way to do it?

thanks

Comment: Which part of your attempt so far isn't working? And what language/tool are you using?

Comment: What is the connection between this string, HTML and DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [expression](http://regex101.com/r/aE2oM7):

```
Name:\s*(.*?)
```

We first match `Name:` literally, followed by 0+ whitespace characters (`\s*`).  Then we [lazily capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) 0+ characters (`(.*?)`).

Comment: Perfect thank you - I made a slight change to    Name:\s*(.*) and will repeat this for each part. Thanks

Comment: Good call @Franco, wasn't thinking clearly..I updated my answer to include that :)

Answer (score 1):

### An Example with Sed

Just print lines with leading spaces. For example, with sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]\+//p' /tmp/corpus 
Franco Donezzi  
01234567890
franco@franco.com
16/12/2014
28/12/2014
2 adults, 0 children
this is the text I want to match. there could be any amount of plain text here spread over multiple lines. sldkfjsldkfjs
```